# Compare each element of two series/df with a custom function in pandas without a for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, longest-substring

I built a custom function two compare two url's to get the longest common subsequence (lcs).

```
def lcs_dynamic(url1, url2): 
   maths: compare url1 with url2
   return lcs
```

I have a series s1 and a series s2 with a bunch of url's (13.000pcs). I want to compare each element of both series with each other (169.000.000 comparisons)

I did it with two nested for-loops, but it's way too slow.

```
for index1, value1 in s1.items():
    for index2, value2 in s2.items():
        url1 = value1
        url2 = value2
        if (index1 != index2):
            lcs1 = lcs_dynamic(url1, url2) //usage of my custom function
        overlap = lcs1 /len(url2)
        print({index1}, {index2}, {url1}, {url2}, {overlap})
```

Is there a better way to do it?

I thought about the apply() method, but I couldn't figure out how to get access to series2 and the second url as my custom function lcs_dynamic needs both urls as arguments

`series1.apply(lcs_dynamic(url1, url2))` --> in this case I would get the url1 from series1 but how can get access to the series2 and url2... don't know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for an algorithm to compare each URL in Series s1 with the URLs in Series S2 ? Are you trying to find the index # of S2 for each S1?

Comment: you could use apply as `df.apply(lambda row : lcs_dynamic(row['series1'], row['series2']), axis = 1)`

Comment: @JoeFerndz No, I have the index # of both.

Comment: @heretolearn thanks mate. will i get then all the variatons?

Comment: for all variations i suppose you would have to first do a cross join of both series to generate all possible combinations and then apply the custom function for each combination

Comment: @heretolearn that's a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments above :

First, define the two dataframes containing the series:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'url1' : ['url1/path1/subpath1/subpath2', 'url2/path2/subpath1/subpath2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url2' : ['url1/path1/subpath1', 'url2/path2/subpath1']})
```

Next, do a cross join to generate all the possible combinations:

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')
```

Next, apply the custom function:

```
df['lcs'] = df.apply(lambda row : lcs_dynamic(row['url1'], row['url2']), axis = 1)
df['overlap'] = df['lcs'] / df['url2'].str.len()
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! 
But I was missing my indexes from both series/ dataframes. I now transformed the indexes from both dataframes into columns and it worked out! I have now a dataframe with:
index_df1    |    url1    |    index_df2   |   url2   |  lcs   |    overlapp

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine so far. But how do i get rid of the duplicates. As i do a cross-join i will get for example

```
(1;1), (1;2), (1;3)
(2;1), (2;2), (2;3)
```

I want to remove the duplicates (1;1), (2;2) etc.. But as well the duplicates (1;2) and (2;1), cause they are for me the same.